# Application_AuthenticateRequest Executing first before a Forms authentication ticket is created

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication, global-asax

I am having trouble while using role based security with Forms Authentication, every time I try and login for the first time ticket seems to have no UserData as Application_Authenticate request is executing first, and my if statements is not executing as the roles are none after first post back.

please help!

My Sign In click event:

```
 protected void signin_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con.Open();
    }
    HashData ob = new HashData();//Custom Class used for Hashing Passwords
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Logincheck", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txt_username.Text.Trim();
    string pass = ob.Encrypt(txt_pass.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = pass;
    SqlParameter result = new SqlParameter("@result", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
    SqlParameter userrole = new SqlParameter("@userrole", SqlDbType.VarChar,50) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
    cmd.Parameters.Add(result); cmd.Parameters.Add(userrole);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    int rslt = Convert.ToInt32(result.Value);
    if (rslt == -1)
    {
        string message = "Login Failed";
        string url = "Login.aspx";
        string script = "window.onload = function(){ alert('";
        script += message;
        script += "');";
        script += "window.location = '";
        script += url;
        script += "'; }";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Redirect", script, true);
    }
    string u_role = userrole.Value.ToString();
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket
        (1, txt_username.Text.Trim(), DateTime.Now,
        DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), false, u_role,
        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
    string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash);
    if (ticket.IsPersistent)
    {
        cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
    }
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Admin.aspx");
    }
    if (User.IsInRole("manager"))
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Manager/Manager.aspx");
    }
    if (User.IsInRole("teamlead"))
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Teamlead/Teamlead.aspx");
    }
    if (User.IsInRole("qa"))
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
    }
    cmd.Dispose();
    con.Close();
}
```

And my Global.ASAX File

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is FormsIdentity)
            {
                FormsIdentity id = (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = id.Ticket;
                string userData = ticket.UserData;
                string[] roles = userData.Split(',');
                HttpContext.Current.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(id, roles);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself, User.IsInRole will be effective after the forms authentication ticket is made and our principal object is made,i.e. after postback.

So to solve this i used static roles from database only to redirect.

```
 protected void signin_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con.Open();
    }
    HashData ob = new HashData();//Custom Class used for Hashing Passwords
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Logincheck", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txt_username.Text.Trim();
    string pass = ob.Encrypt(txt_pass.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = pass;
    SqlParameter result = new SqlParameter("@result", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
    SqlParameter userrole = new SqlParameter("@userrole", SqlDbType.VarChar,50) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
    cmd.Parameters.Add(result); cmd.Parameters.Add(userrole);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    int rslt = Convert.ToInt32(result.Value);
    if (rslt == -1)
    {
        string message = "Login Failed";
        string url = "Login.aspx";
        string script = "window.onload = function(){ alert('";
        script += message;
        script += "');";
        script += "window.location = '";
        script += url;
        script += "'; }";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Redirect", script, true);
    }
    string u_role = userrole.Value.ToString();
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket
        (1, txt_username.Text.Trim(), DateTime.Now,
        DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), false, u_role,
        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
    string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash);

    if (ticket.IsPersistent)
    {
        cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
    }
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
   // Response.Redirect("Redirecting.aspx");

    if (u_role == "admin")
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Admin.aspx");
    }
    if (u_role == "admin" || u_role == "manager")
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Manager/Manager.aspx");
    }
    if (u_role == "teamlead" || u_role == "admin" || u_role == "manager")
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Teamlead/Teamlead.aspx");
    }
    if (u_role == "qa")
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
    cmd.Dispose();
    con.Close();
}
```

So it is working fine now,

Thanks.